# how python by php code

Tags: php, python

I want to  pass the multiple variable from php to python .And print those variable values through python code .(python3.4,runnning in localhost)
This is my sample code:

```
<?php
$v1 = "1";
$v2 = "2";
$v3 = "3";
exec ( "/cgi-bin/z1.py $v1 $v2 $v3" );
?>
```

Python code:

```
#!c:/Python34/python.exe -u
import sys 
import cgitb ,cgi

print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()
print (sys.argv[1]) 
print (sys.argv[2]) 
print (sys.argv[3])
```

But in output it's not  printing the variable values.Please suggest how can i sent the values or I did a mistake while specifying  path

Comment: where are you storing your python file , based on 1st line of your py file i suspect you are using windows.

Comment: you  have to provide full path here -> exec ( "/cgi-bin/z1.py $v1 $v2 $v3" );

Comment: ya . iam using windows ,so it's stored under xampp/cgi-bin

Comment: try to give full path in exec (pyhton.exe "C:\blah_blah\z1.py ......")

Comment: tried using exec(pyhton.exe "D:\xampp\cgi-bin\z1.py $v1 $v2 $v3" ); giving error as  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"' in D:\xampp\htdocs\z1.php

Comment: python.exe should be inside the quote

Comment: `exec("pyhton.exe D:\xampp\cgi-bin\z1.py $v1 $v2 $v3" );` try this

Comment: same thing not printing any value

Comment: is your python.exe in the path? if not use full path `exec("C:\python\blahblah\pyhton.exe D:\xampp\cgi-bin\z1.py $v1 $v2 $v3" );`

Comment: no still it's not working

Comment: exec("C:\Python34\pyhton.exe D:\xampp\cgi-bin\z1.py $v1 $v2 $v3" );

Answer (score 0):

Couple of typos:

```
 exec("C:\Python34\pyhton.exe D:\xampp\cgi-bin\z1.py $v1 $v2 $v3" )
                     ↑↑         ↑↑↑
```

In double quotes hexescapes `\xAA` get interpreted as byte sequences.

- User either single quotes.
- Or standard path specifiers:

  ```
   exec("python 'D:/xampp/cgi-bin/z1.py' $v1 $v2 $v3")
  ```

Don't forget [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) for reliable argument passing.

Comment: i tried with standard path specifiers and single quotes but it's not printing any value